# Commitlog sync period

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, scylla

According to cassandra commit log sync period..data first goes to os buffer...then from os buffer, based on commit log sync period ,the buffer data gets synced to commit log file in disk..and the default sync period is 10 seconds..what if server crashes in that 10 secs.. data is lost ryt? But the client got a response as SUCCESS the moment data is written to commitlog buffer in os buffer and memtable..but eventually data is lost because system crashed within that 10 sec window...am i missing something?

Answer (score 10):

You are not missing anything. Databases like Cassandra and Scylla not only tradeoff consistency for availability under failures, but, like traditional databases like Postgres, also tradeoff durability for performance. You can change the `commitlog_sync` option to `batch` or decrease the `commitlog_sync_period_in_ms`; note that if you do this, it is best to have the commitlog stored in a different media than the data directory.

The reasoning behind this is that durability can be achieved through persistency but also through replication. A typical Cassandra/Scylla user will usually have `RF = 3`, and write with a consistency level of `QUORUM`, such that you'd need coordinated failures of multiple machines to actually lose data.

Answer (score 3):

(Disclaimer: I'm a ScyllaDB employee)

I think what you are missing is that the data is written to commitlog **on disk** and to the memtable simultaneously, and assuming you are using RF > 1 with CL > 1 (e.g. quorum) than even if a specific node crashed the other replicas will still have the data, which can later be repaired.

If you are using RF > 1 and CL = ONE, there's also a chance that if the node crashed before the replica was synced, than the data will be lost.

If the entire cluster goes down, or in case of a single node cluster than indeed you client can get the SUCCESS ACK back, yet the data will be lost.

You are welcome to check Scylla Architecture docs for better understanding:

- http://docs.scylladb.com/architecture/architecture-fault-tolerance/
- http://docs.scylladb.com/architecture/console_CL_full_demo/

Comment: Thats wrong ryt in case of single node cluster, or cluster with rf=1 ,user is getting wrong status, he is getting success but actually it has failed and data is lost...

Comment: I was assuming RF>1 and I wrote it explicitly. I added more info.

Comment: @RupeshMukherjee in case of rf=1, a permanent crash of a node will lead to permanent loss of data, which is of course much more serious than losing 10 seconds of data. This is why you would not use rf=1 in any real deployment of Cassandra (unless your data is temporary).

Comment: @nyh -  yeah, that is correct, for fail over RF>1 is always needed. But I am just thinking from singe deployment perspective...(let say in dev) .. It will not be parmanent loss of data , as once servr is back, your persistent(SS table) data is back but that 10 second data is permanently lost ... But anyway thanks guyz.. my intent was to understand the concept,which is clear now..